# Define custom colormap matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, gradient

I'm trying to define a custom color gradient in order to visualize with more detail (colors) the region between 0 a 4 degrees, and with less detail the region between 4 and 25 degrees. I was wondering if it could be possible to define and exponential color gradient in order to have more colors in the 0 to 4 region and less in the 4 to 25 region. Any ideas?

Thanks!

The picture shows a standard linear color gradient.

[image: Temperature gradient]

Comment: **Custom colormap

Comment: have a look here : https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_cmap.html

Comment: Thanks @jadsq! The link in the Arbitrary colorbar post helped me.